# ora-000947 in PIPELINED function

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, pipeline

I create some function which returns table. I create record, then make record as table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE FOR_SELECT AS TYPE NK IS RECORD (
  SHT   NUMBER,
  VVD   NUMBER,
  NEKOM NUMBER,
  N_GOL NUMBER);
TYPE NK_T IS TABLE OF NK;  FUNCTION NEK_SLU_PR(W_KOD VARCHAR2)
RETURN NK_T PIPELINED;  END FOR_SELECT;
```

AND MY SIMPLE FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY FOR_SELECT  AS   FUNCTION NEK_SLU_PR(W_KOD VARCHAR2)
RETURN NK_T PIPELINED
AS
  REC   NK_T;

  SHT   NUMBER;
  VVD   NUMBER;
  NEKOM NUMBER;
  N_GOL NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SHT := 3;
  VVD := 4;
  NEKOM := 5;
  N_GOL := 6;


  SELECT SHT,
         VVD,
         NEKOM,
         N_GOL
    INTO REC
    FROM DUAL;

  PIPE ROW (REC);
  RETURN;
END NEK_SLU_PR;END FOR_SELECT;
```

I have 4 variables and all select in variable which have table type, but ora-000947 - not enough values( what I do  wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REC` has the wrong type.

It should be `NK` instead of `NK_T`, since you deal with a single record.

Answer (score 1):

> --Try this it will help you to understand about pipelined functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NK IS OBJECT (
  SHT   NUMBER,
  VVD   NUMBER,
  NEKOM NUMBER,
  N_GOL NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NK_T IS TABLE OF NK;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEK_SLU_PR(
    W_KOD VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NK_T PIPELINED
AS
  REC NK_T;
  SHT   NUMBER;
  VVD   NUMBER;
  NEKOM NUMBER;
  N_GOL NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SHT   := 3;
  VVD   := 4;
  NEKOM := 5;
  N_GOL := 6;
  SELECT NK(SHT, VVD, NEKOM, N_GOL) BULK COLLECT INTO  REC FROM DUAL;
  FOR I IN 1..REC.COUNT 
    LOOP    
        PIPE ROW( NK( REC(I).sht,REC(I).vvd, REC(I).nekom, REC(I).n_gol ) ) ;
    END LOOP ;
  RETURN;
END NEK_SLU_PR;

---------------------------------------------OUTPUT-------------------------------------------

select * from table(NEK_SLU_PR('av'));


SHT VVD NEKOM   N_GOL
3      4     5     6


---------------------------------------------OUTPUT-------------------------------------------
```